On the units of NRT-dpa electronic losses formula (Lindhard)
I'm trying to convert the PKA energy into damage energy following equation (5) of the NRT-dpa model article. In Fig. 1 you have an example of what you should get. Let's take $E=40keV$ (PKA), therefore $\hat{E}=30keV$ (damage).
I think my prblem is due to that units are not specified in the equations (numercial approximations). Which is obviously wrong. Also this book shows the equations, but units aren't specified either; see Eq (2.50) and below.
This is my calculation. Take iron, $Z_1=Z_2=26$, $A_1=A_2=55.845$. Bohr radius $a_0=0.529177\times10^{-10}m$ and electronic charge $e=1.602\times10^{-19}C$. To be consistent, $E=40keV=6.4\times10^{-15}J$.

Eq (9): $a=1.12\times10^{-11}$
Eq (8): $\epsilon=2.07\times10^9$
Eq (7): $k=0.157$
Eq (6): $g(\epsilon)=2.07\times10^9$
Eq (5): $\hat{E}=1.23\times10^{-7}keV$

$g$ is too big.
